# JScrollPane in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a `JScrollPane`, which has a `JPanel` for its content pane. To that `JPanel` I add smaller `JPanel`s, and as expected, if I add too much `JPanel`, a vertical scrollbar will appear.

The problem is, that my small `JPanel`s contains a `JScrollPane` too for a `JEditorPane`. I'd like to use the mouse wheel *only* for the outer scrollpane, not for the smaller scrollpane. I already set `wheelScrollingEnabled()` to `false` for the small scrollpane, but if I scroll in any direction, and the mouse gets over the `JEditorPane`, the scrolling doesn't work anymore.

Any advice?

Comment: +1 for the interesting catch: my expectation would have been that setting the wheelScrollEnabled to false would do the trick :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try to forward the wheel events from the inner scroll pane to its parent.

```
innerScrollPane.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        innerScrollPane.getParent().dispatchEvent(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: good dirty workaround :-) The behaviour (of not reverting to dispatching the wheelEvent to the ancestor on wheelScrollEnabled == false) is a bug in BasicScrollPaneUI, IMO - it should add/remove the internally installed wheelListener as appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Add a `MouseWheelListener` to your `JScrollPane` and when handling an event, pass it to the main `JScrollPane` by invoking its `dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)` method;

Comment: no, unnecessarily hard-coding dependencies is not an option, especially not as the editorPane has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Agree, it the listener should be registered with the JScrollPane.

Comment: better, but still hard-coding a dependency from inner to main ;-) look at @Howard's solution for a hard-coded free approach

Comment: Yeh, I know, that's why I upvoted @Howard's answer... I just corrected my answer so that it at least not wrong.